# 1 IP or 2 IPs for a dedicated server. Which is better?

Tags: dns, ip, hosting

We ordered a dedicated server for our website example.com and expected to have 2 IPs - one for ns1.example.com and one for ns2.example.com. But the provider has allocated the same IP for both ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com giving us a spare IP address that we can use for something else. They have offered to change it to two IPs but now we're not sure which is better.

Nobody is using our site right now but we hope it will be very popular in the future and we don't want anything to hold us back. So what are the pros and cons of having one IP address or two? Which is better for us going forward?

Thanks

Comment: The dedicated server to be used as a Name Server? Since you mentioned ns1 and ns2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Loadbalancing point of view - If both IP addresses are given to same server, than it doesn't serve the purpose.

Just curious in era of cloud, why use dedicated server? Any specific reason.

Comment: I don't understand your first point. Could you explain? Regarding your second point we're running an api and we assumed dedicated was better. Are we wrong?

Comment: Point 1 - If the reason to have 2 ip addresses is for handling traffic, than it doesn't make sense if traffic is going to come on same server from both ip addresses.   Point 2 - Check the cost efficiency compared to cloud, everything else is fine.

Comment: I get Point 1 now thanks. Regarding point 2 we need high security and 100% uptime. Can we get that with Cloud?

Comment: Yes you can get both on cloud, world's top websites/apis run on cloud.

Comment: can you recommend a provider we can trust?

Comment: there are many including big names like google and aws. You can research and choose as per your need.